# is it really helpful? how will it change the world?

Tags: blockchain

I have been interested in learning more about cryptocurrencies due to the fact that they are on the verge of changing our financial market. However, I want a definitive answer as to why cryptocurrencies are going to lead us into a new era? is it a good investment for the future?